# plotting very long time series - scroll bars?

Tags: graph, scroll, gnuplot

I have a very long time series of data to plot, and if I "zoom in" enough to see the interesting features, I can only look at a very small section of the data, and must replot every time I want to look at a different time window.

What I would like is a solution that gives me a graph with a horizontal scroll bar so I can browse around within the long time series.

My current preferred solution is gnuplot/aquaterm on OS X. It doesn't appear that this can do what I want - I can specify "set size 2.0,1.0" but this just causes the graph to spill over the window bounds, without causing a scroll bar to appear.

Can anybody recommend a solution that will do what I want - preferably with gnuplot, but any solution would do. I could of course write my own gnuplot gui terminal (or mess around with aquaterm), but I don't unfortunately have time for that!

Thanks for any suggestions.
Jonny

Answer (score 1):

If you use an image terminal you can make it arbitrarily wide:

```
set terminal png size [width]x[height]
set output '[fname].png
```

Then open the output png file in an image viewer that scrolls.